# Translating an MS Excel formula to C#

Tags: c#

## EDIT

Just check what @Sam Axe answered:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double a = (new DateTime(2020, 9, 30) - new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)).TotalDays;
        double b = (new DateTime(1994, 7, 31) - new DateTime(1900, 1, 1)).TotalDays;

        Console.WriteLine(( a - 0.8 * b ) / 365.25) ; // 45.08!
    }
}
```

## ORIGINAL

I have this MS Excel formula:

```
=(AI14 - 80% * MAX(EOMONTH($J$12;12*18),"31/07/1994")) / 365.25
```

Where AI14 is the last day of the birthday month of a person in the current year; EOMONTH($J$12;12*18) is the last day of the birthday month when a person completed 18 years of age.

I created a EOMONTH method in a static C# class:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static DateTime EOMonth(DateTime someDate)
    {
        return new DateTime(someDate.Year, someDate.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(someDate.Year, someDate.Month));
    }

    // Calculate age
    public static int CalculateAge(DateTime dateOfBirth, DateTime refDate)
    {
        return (int)((refDate - dateOfBirth).TotalDays / 365.25);
    }
}
```

Then I use `Helper.EOMonth((dateOfBirth).AddYears(age))` to get the same result from AI14 in MS Excel.

To get the result from `MAX(EOMONTH($J$12;12*18),"31/07/1994")` I do the following:

## [FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7FOdIX)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime dateOfBirth = new DateTime(1961, 9, 3);
        byte age = (byte)Helper.CalculateAge(dateOfBirth, DateTime.Now);
        DateTime lastDayBirthdayMonthCurrentYear = Helper.EOMonth((dateOfBirth).AddYears(age));

        DateTime dateWhenThePersonWas18 = Helper.EOMonth((dateOfBirth).AddYears(18));
        DateTime referenceDate = new DateTime(1994, 7, 31);

        DateTime maxDate = new DateTime(Math.Max(referenceDate.Ticks, dateWhenThePersonWas18.Ticks));

        Console.WriteLine(lastDayBirthdayMonthCurrentYear);

        Console.WriteLine(dateWhenThePersonWas18);

        Console.WriteLine(maxDate);

        // Putting all together
        // It gives an error because I cannot apply '*' to DateTime and double
        // double factor = (lastDayBirthdayMonthCurrentYear  - 0.8 * maxDate ) / 365.25;

    }

}


public static class Helper
{
    public static DateTime EOMonth(DateTime data)
    {
        return new DateTime(data.Year, data.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(data.Year, data.Month)); ;
    }

    // Calculate age
    public static int CalculateAge(DateTime dateOfBirth, DateTime refDate)
    {
        return (int)((refDate - dateOfBirth).TotalDays / 365.25);
    }
}
```

What really bugs me here is that the person who created that formula is calculating a % of a date.

**For this example (same date of birth), the factor calculated by MS Excel is 45.08, but I don't even know if it's right, because I never came across such a situation where a person needed to calculate a percentage of a date. What does that even mean?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to verify this.. I'm just going by memory and a quick Google search..

But Excel stores dates as an integer representing the number of days since midnight JAN 01 1900 plus a decimal portion of a 24-hour day representing the time.  So 2.5 would represent JAN 03 1900 at noon.

So you can easily figure what 80% of that would be.  Though why anyone would want to do that is entirely beyond me in the 3 seconds I've spent on this questions.